# Displaying once repeat elements on array with jquery or php

Tags: php, jquery

How to display once elements of array ?. For example

```
var array = ["b","c","c","a","d","e","a","d"]

show => ["a","b","c","d","e"] ?
```

Any example ?

Comment: Have a look to [array_unique](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) for a PHP function.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript array sort and unique](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4833651/javascript-array-sort-and-unique)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `array_unique()` function to remove the duplicates and sort - http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php

Following up with the `array_values()` function will remove the gaps in the array index - http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php

```
// initialize array
var $array = array("b","c","c","a","d","e","a","d");
// remove duplicates and sort by string value
$array = array_unique($array, SORT_STRING);
// reindex array (numeric index will have gaps where the duplicates where removed)
$array = array_values($array);
// show results
print_r($array);
```

In Javascript/jQuery you can use the `unique()` and `sort()` methods

```
// initialize array
var array = ["b","c","c","a","d","e","a","d"];
// remove duplicate values
array.unique();
// sort remaining items
array.sort();
```

If you are sorting numbers in Javascript, you would need to pass a function, as the array is sorted lexicographically be default

```
array.sort(function(a,b){return a - b;});
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP

```
array_unique($array, SORT_STRING)
```

jQuery

```
array.unique()
```

Answer (score 0):

in php you should use `array_unique` and `sort` for sorting array

```
$arr = array("b","c","c","a","d","e","a","d");
sort($arr);
print_r(array_unique($arr));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var names = ["Mike","Matt","Nancy","Adam","Jenny","Nancy","Carl"];
var uniqueNames = [];
$.each(names, function(i, el){
    if($.inArray(el, uniqueNames) === -1) uniqueNames.push(el);
});
```

source:[stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229645/remove-duplicates-from-javascript-array)

Comment: A much easier solution would be to use `names.unique()`

Comment: yes ,i posted bcoz he asked for solution either in php or js

Comment: `unique()` is a Javascript function, PHP has a similar function `array_unique()`. Javascript syntax is `array.unique()` and PHP is `array_unique($array)`.

Answer (score 0):

---

qustion asked:-
How to display once elements of array ?. For example

var array = ["b","c","c","a","d","e","a","d"]

show => ["a","b","c","d","e"] ?

Any example ?

---

answer:-
$arr = array("b","c","a","d","e","a","d");

$unique = array_unique($arr);//remove all duplicate values

sort($unique);//sort is done here

echo "";
print_r($unique );//shows show => ["a","b","c","d","e"]