# How to return unique and sorted array values useing jQuery?

Tags: jquery, arrays, sorting, unique

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript array sort and unique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4833651/javascript-array-sort-and-unique)

I was surprised to see that there is no built in jQuery function for that.

I've seen many solutions on stackoverflow, but the questions were polluted with not-working answers (to find a working one I had to test them all).

So, for future reference and to spare other users the trouble I decided to post this Q&A style.

## How to return unique and sorted array values useing jQuery?

#### Numbers:

```
// input array
var inputArray = [10, 5, 15, 10, 5, 15];

// expected result array
var resultArray = [5, 10, 15];
```

#### Strings:

```
// input array
var inputArray = ['b', 'a', 'c', 'b', 'a', 'c'];

// expected result array
var resultArray = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
```

Comment: wooh you answered your own question at the same time ?

Comment: @Sibu That's totally legit on SO : if you solve a problem and have a solution that may help others, you can do what OP did. But in this specific case I don't think it's interesting enough as it's yet frequently answered.

Comment: @dystroy agreed but why ask an question when you know the answer, if you see OP question time and answer time, both are nearly same..amusing isn't it ?

Comment: The reason is to help other people : if the question is new and interesting and you think you have special knowledge, then you may bring it to the masses. See [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12513/should-i-not-answer-my-own-questions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will take upon myself to add my answer here, instead of the previously asked question simply because the answer in the previously asked question is bad, but I don't hope for the author to alter the decision.

Now, to give you some more intuition into the solution that I propose: Sorting is O(n log n), removing duplicates is O(n), so we conclude that the entire operation should be no more complex then n log n. However, if you think of it, n will never increase, but will most likely decrease if you first remove duplicates, and *then* sort. So, while on the surface of it, it is still O(n log n), it will be generally faster. You could probably improve it (in other languages) by collecting values into a tree instead of a hash-table, but given the tremendous difference in performance between the "native" data structures and custom ones in JavaScript - the solution below should be optimal:

```
function sortUnique(array) {
    "use strict";
    var table = {}, key, i;
    for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        table[[array[i]]] = '';
    }
    i = 0;
    for (key in table) {
        array[i++] = key;
    }
    array.length = i;
    return array.sort();
}
sortUnique(['b', 'a', 'c', 'b', 'a', 'c']);
// [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ]
```

Comment: Are you sure it's faster ? Especially for a not gigantic array ?

Comment: I will test your solution, if it works and is faster I will obviously mark it as correct, no need for comments like "but I don't hope for the author to alter the decision".

Comment: I'm marking this as accepted becouse it works and also i've learned a lesson about performance. tyvm wvxvw

Comment: If the array contains numbers or Dates, this alg converts them to strings in IE or node.js. The reason is (if I understand well) that `table[[...]]` is a nonstandard feature, present in ECMA6 draft only, not implemented in IE "yet" (2 years later than the above answer!). In ECMA5, [object keys must always be converted to strings](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6066846).

Answer (score 0):

As a function:

```
function sort_unique(arr) {
    return arr.sort(function(a,b){
        return (a > b) ? 1 : -1;
    }).filter(function(el,i,a) {
        return (i==a.indexOf(el));
    });
}
```

Comment: I never said my solution was the fastest one. I posted a simple and working solution. The question was not "what is the fastest way to..."?

Answer (score 0):

hope this will work for you

```
var dummy = [10, 5, 15, 10, 5, 15];
var arr = [];
$.map(arr, function(n, i){
  if($.inArray(n, arr) == -1)
      arr.push(n);
});
```

now in arr values are unique. now you can apply any sorting algo on this.