# How can i get the number without repetition?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

i want to get the number with only one repitition:

```js
let results = [2, 2, 1, 2, 3, 3, 1]
let pivot = 1
let cont = 0
let unitaries = []
for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
  if (pivot !== results[i + 1]) {
    pivot = results[i]
    if (cont === 0) {
      unitaries.push(results[i])
      results.splice(i, 1);
    }
    cont++
  }
}
console.log(unitaries)
```

i want to get `[1,2,1]`, but right now i am getting only `[2]`

Comment: Don't delete from the array you're iterating over.

Comment: Please elaborate on what you are trying to do.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript array sort and unique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4833651/javascript-array-sort-and-unique) Just remove Sort

Comment: @filimonic It shouldn't remove all duplicates. Just consecutive duplicates. Notice that the desired result has `1` twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just overwrite your original array using `Array.prototype.filter`:

```js
let results = [2, 2, 1, 2, 3, 3, 1];

results = results.filter(
    (n, i, array) => n !== array[i - 1] && n !== array[i + 1]
);

console.log(results); // [1, 2, 1]
```

Comment: but i need to delete that element from origin results array

Comment: Does my updated answer help? I just reversed the previous `filter()`.

Comment: @RoboRobok I think he means he needs to modify the original array in place.

Comment: @Barmar it shouldn't make any difference in most cases.

Comment: @jdode If you're modifying the original array, why do you print the `unitaries` array?

Comment: @jdode After you're done you can do `results.splice(0, results.length, ...unitaries)` to overwrite the original array.

Comment: @Barmar but it's a `let`, so it can be overwritten.

Answer (score 1):

Here it is modifying original array.

```js
const results = [2, 2, 1, 2, 3, 3, 1]
for (let i = 0; i < results.length;) 
{
  let j = i;
  while (j < results.length)
  {
    if (results[j] === results[i]) j++;
    else break; 
  }
  if ((j - 1) > i) results.splice(i, j - i);
  else i++;
}
console.log(results);
```